# Mantis leg hurt during molt, will it heal?

Tags: molting

My kid got a young mantis -- I believe from the Tamolanica genus -- which just had a difficult molt.  One leg was stuck in the exuvia for a few hours.  After finally separating, it's clear that the mantis isn't able to use that leg for much.  Does not walk with it, cannot grip with it, it's just out there doing nothing.  Other legs are fine and the mantis is mobile.

Is this a permanent injury for the mantis, or can we expect the leg to heal at some point?  The mantis is fairly young and should have a few more molts to go.

Comment: a picture had been helpful for the one(s) answering this question.